# LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item, but the item is there

Tags: enumerate, itemize, missing

I'm trying to write a list in an enumerate environment, but for some reason even if the code is (apparently) correct, Latex gives me the following error at the second line:
"! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item."

Point is, this the code;

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item La soluzione per $\theta$ da' la conferma che il moto si svolge su un piano;
    \item La soluzione per $\phi$ restituisce la conservazione della velocità aerolare;
    \item La soluzione per r è la nota equazione dell'ellisse.
\end{enumerate}
```

And it follows the rules that I've seen on basically every LaTeX manuals on the internet, this "missing \item" is clearly there. I also have already the `\usepackage{enumitem}` activated, I'd say is also pretty standard.
Someone might say that I could just skip it, the problem is that if I compile the code, this is the only error I get; If I delete this whole part of the code, the same error shows up on the following "itemize" or "enumerate" environment and so on, and that basically would mean that I should get ride of every list of the document to make it work, which is not exactly doable in a thesis. Maybe the solution is pretty dumb, but really I can't wrap my head around it.
Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
Ok, following your advices I tried to find the specific lines that are the sources of the problem and this is what I got

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Potenziale.png} 
\caption{potenziale}
\flushleft
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\newpage
\begin{enumerate}
    \item La soluzione per $\theta$ da' la conferma che il moto si svolge su un piano;
    \item La soluzione per $\phi$ restituisce la conservazione della velocità aerolare;
    \item La soluzione per r è la nota equazione dell'ellisse.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Normally, between the \newpage command and the part that I wrote before there are something like 200 lines of code. Clearly you don't have the source image so I suppose the code can't be ported somewhere else, but this is the situation.
I tried to delete the image linked and it works; I can go on without the pic anyway, so at least the problem is solved (though i'm still curious why an image in a totally different part of the document would resulte in a "missing \item" )

Comment: I composed a working example with your code (follow the link: http://ix.io/2Est) . Please compose one with the error you get.

Comment: My cloudy crystal ball says you are doing something that redefined the enumerate environment to take an argument. Also, carefully check the line number given in the error message!

Comment: There is no point in posting a working fragment and asking about an error in code you have not posted. Please edit the question so the example is a complete small document that shows the error.

Comment: start from a _copy_ of  your document, delete everything after the enumerate, delete everything before the enumerate that you can delete while still showing the error, the delete any `\usepackage` not used in the resulting small example, and post the resulting document here. Then someone can debug the error.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I should've thought before that reporting the correct code would have been useless. I'm sorry, this is the first time I have a problem with LateX that I couldn't solve by myself.

Comment: I can't say whether it will fix the problem, but `\newpage` isn't needed (or wanted) after `\clearpage`, and it's also usually better to leave a blank line after a figure.  Not relevant to problem: to insert a block of code here, leave a blank line, enter the code, then highlight the block with the mouse and click on the  `{}` icon above the answer box.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Somehow it has to do with the stray `\flushleft` at the end of the `figure` environment, but I cannot really understand how exactly the error originates.

Answer (score 2):

The `\flushleft` is an error, because it is actually an artifact of the `flushleft` environment, which encloses ragged-right text set off from the running text with vertical spaces (at begin and end). If you want a command version, the command is `\raggedright`. (I presume it should go before the `\includegraphics`.)

How does it interact with `\item`? The `flushleft` definition uses a "trivial list" to get the vertical spacing of lists.

(This answer comes after the question was editied with revealing information.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Should `\@trivlist` really assign `\@newlisttrue` globally but `\@item` sets `\everypar` locally to undo the setting..

Answer (score 0):

This works with me. (I changed the accents though)

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item La soluzione per $\theta$ da' la conferma che il moto si svolge su un piano;
\item La soluzione per $\phi$ restituisce la conservazione della velocit\`a aerolare;
\item La soluzione per r \`e la nota equazione dell'ellisse.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

in "standalone":

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{12cm}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item La soluzione per $\theta$ da' la conferma che il moto si svolge su un piano;
            \item La soluzione per $\phi$ restituisce la conservazione della velocit\`a aerolare;
            \item La soluzione per r \`e la nota equazione dell'ellisse.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention it, the code worked just fine when I copied it and paste in a new tex file. This would normally lead to believe that the problem lies somewhere else, possibly right before/after the environment, but if that would be the case, then it would be an isolated mistake; instead, as I said before, if I delete totally this part of the code, the same error shows up on the next itemize/enumerate environment and so on. For reference, in the original document there's just a line of introduction before the posted code and there's nothign after (just the beginning of a new section).

Comment: What documentclass are you using?

Comment: Article. This piece of code comes from a thesis for a bachelor

Comment: There it should work as well. In e.g. standalone, this will not work. Can you post the (minimal) document that fails? In those document classes you can use it but you have to place it in a minipage (so that \LaTeX\ knows the width of the text). I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Well, I have no idea on how to do this. The entire document have more than 900 lines of code and the lines that cause the error are the one that I wrote before and as you have seen, copying and pasting single lines doesn't show any error at all.

Comment: Also, I tried to change the document class in both "report" and "standalone". In report the error shows up again, but not in standalone, at least with the code you added after the edit. I don't know how feasible it is to change the document class after writing 30 page of this thing but it might be a solution, even if by doing it latex gave me something like ten other errors, presumably because of the change. Thank you anyway, I might take this in consideration as a solution

Comment: Sorry, standalone is meant for very short images, not for big documents. I suggest you delete some of the 900 lines to come up with a smaller file. I cannot help you if I cannot reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case another poor soul like me comes here in search of an answer.

This error is also output when you don't separate two enumerations with a new paragraph, be it `\par` or a blank line.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item AAA
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item BBB
\end{enumerate}
```

barfs `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item`, while

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item AAA
\end{enumerate}\par
\begin{enumerate}
    \item BBB
\end{enumerate}
```

works fine.